# fitting a smaller range

Tags: kitchens

when we bought our house, it had a very used 40" gas range. now that range has died. replacing with a new 40" range is very pricey ($2k+), and our cooking needs don't justify the size anyhow.

i'm looking for ideas on how to fit a smaller range. i would imagine that extending the counter top and cabinets would be a pretty extensive change. we've found we can get a 36" range for around 1/2 the cost. would it be feasible to add some sort of storage along side the smaller range to fill in the space?

thanks. i know this is an open-ended question with no specific answer, i'm just looking for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shop around, if you can wait a bit - folks remodel and put them on craigslist somewhat regularly; or look more seriously at having the range you have repaired, if you have not (unclear how far you went down that road before declaring it dead) as it may cost less than anything else, even if it feels expensive. For most ranges, a good rebuilder can not only restore function, but also remove most of the "very used" look and feel. Ask to see examples of their work. You may need to look to a larger city you'd have to drive to in order  to find one, but appliance rebuilders are out there.

The problem with "adding storage" is that you are only looking at 4" less width, so by the time you put in a couple of cabinet sides you've got a space that can be handy for cookie sheets, but not much else - if you don't extend the countertop over it, it looks weird (and collects crud, spills, grease etc), and if you do, it still looks weird, unless you can actually get a full-on match (possible with some stone and solid surface materials, and a good contractor - but it may cost you enough to make the replacement stove at 40" look like a better way to spend your money.)

Comment: thanks. "very used" means it is rusting out on the inside. it's in really poor shape. most recently there was a small electrical fire in the oven (sparking) that didn't stop until i unplugged (turning off the oven didn't help), so i'm concerned about safety.

Comment: Depending on how your base cabinets are arranged and attached, it MAY be possible to free one up and slide it 4", countertop and all.